# Scrapy plaintext error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Python Scrapy. I want to extract the text from the webpage with out HTML tag. below is my code (got idea from this page : [How can I get all the plain text from a website with Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156780/how-can-i-get-all-the-plain-text-from-a-website-with-scrapy))

```
sel = Selector(response)
        item = DeletespiderItem()
        item['url'] =  response.url
        description = sel.select("//body").extract()
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(description)
        item['description'] = tree.text_content().strip()
        yield item
```

but i am getting the below error

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 722, in fromstring
        is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
    exceptions.TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What went wrong in my code. How can i get the plain text from?

Can any one help me ? Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

```
Scapy shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156780/how-can-i-get-all-the-plain-text-from-a-website-with-scrapy

sel.select("//body").extract()[0].strip()
```

o/p \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n chat\r\n ]

It is adding additional \r\n ?

Comment: Give a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413900/scrapy-why-does-my-response-object-not-have-a-body-as-unicode-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932570/scrapy-spider-for-json-response

Comment: Hi @aberna , NOt working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`extract()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.extract) returns a list, use:

```
description = sel.select("//body").extract()[0]
```

Comment: It is working but the problem is [\r\n    \r\n    \r\n        \r\n                \r\n                        \r\n            chat\r\n ] It is adding Extra escape characters \r\n ..

Comment: @Backtrack where are you getting this value, at what step? What if you calls strip here: `sel.select("//body").extract()[0].strip()`? Thanks.

Comment: I did this but did not work  [sel.select("//body").extract()[0].strip()] . Not working

Comment: @Backtrack those newlines is not a problem, get the text as you've planned with `lxml.html`. FYI, call `print(sel.select("//body").extract()[0].strip())` and see there is no newlines.

Comment: When i tried that i am getting this error ['ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 8468: ordinal not in range(128)]

Comment: It is removing the HTML tags  but my problem is the escape characters [\r\n] :(

Comment: @Backtrack what about calling replace: `tree.text_content().strip().replace('\n', '')`?